# How to connect to azure sql from local visual studio environment without storing connection string?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

net core and azure sql. I am trying to connect to azure sql from my local visual studio. If I am deploying app in app service I can make use of managed identities. Currently I am app in local environment. I do not want to store any password in local ystem like appsettings.json. I am curious to know is there any way where I can connect to azure sql without storing password in local visual studio. Can someone help me if there is any other way? Thank you for help.

Comment: For connecting [`Azure SQL`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/) this are the parameter you need `Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDataBase;User ID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;` If you don't want to store in your project in that case you can use [azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview#securely-store-secrets-and-keys). Thus, you need to save key-vault in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Azure AD based authentication for SQL Databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview?view=azuresql). Assuming you are signed-in into Visual Studio using your Azure AD credentials, you can assign yourself a database role in the SQL Database using a command like:

```
CREATE USER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE [<databse-role-name e.g. dbmanager>] ADD MEMBER [AzureAD_object]
```

Once you do that, you should be able to connect to your SQL Database using a connection string like the following:

```
Server=tcp:<db-server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Default;Database=<db-name>;TrustServerCertificate=true;
```

Please see these links for more details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-logins-tutorial?view=azuresql

Comment: This link is also useful for dornet apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16